# Less: remove all faulty lines on compiling

Tags: php, css, less

in a current project I need to port the existing css source to less, including a simple css-template engine.
I've got the css structure in one file and then several files (css-templates) with different values for the variables used in the structure, mainly changing colors and the like. All templates @import the structure file and compile great.

The problem comes up when trying to compile a template that does not "use" (define) some variables. Prior to less we had a PHP driven system that would simply remove all lines from the structure that contained not defined variables - but lessc only throws errors and won't compile. Setting up defaults for every variable in use is not an option as this would include setting up bare css defaults like "none", "repeat" and the like, which is no real solution.

**Is there any way I can compile less files while removing all lines that contain not defined variables?**

I thought about writing my own wrapper using some PHP-compiler - but I'd need a compiler that I can recieve these errors from prior to the compiling, does anything like this already exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did SO remove the "consider leaving a comment when downvoting" hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I solved this by writing a wrapper utilizing the lessc command.
I simply try to compile until no errors are returned, removing the faulty lines on the way through.
There seems to be no existing project doing just that, let alone more efficient.

It's really bad when it comes down to performance (compiling one template may take three to four loops of compiling, removing, compiling) but then again, we will only use this prior to deployment.